# Draw multiple tikz pictures in line

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw a few pictures **in line** using tikz. I added a few pictures for your understanding. The first pictures is fine, but in the second is some kind of line break which I don't want.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

The **code** I'm using is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{5pt}

\begin{document}
  \begin{preview}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
      % draw 1
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \hspace*{10pt}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
      % draw 2
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \hspace*{10pt}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
      % draw 3
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{preview}

\end{document}
```

Do you have any ideas how to draw these pictures in line?

Comment: Hi, welcome to TeX.SX. I included the images for you. Once you got 10rep points you can do this by yourself.

Comment: Note that you can write such files even shorter using the [`standalone`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/standalone) *class*: `\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture} ... \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`
You can then include them directly into a main file with the `standalone` *package*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TeX will treat "end-of-line" as additional white space—and these white spaces allow line breaks.

Does it help to add `%` after `\end{tikzpicture}` and after `\hspace*{10pt}`? This should disable the white space caused by end-of-line tokens.

Comment: I added a few '%' and it is working now. Thank you!

Comment: You can use backticks (`\``) to mark your inline code.

Comment: use \begin{scope}[xshift=2cm] \end{scope}